# Hide div with anchor name on pageload and show it only while clicking the link

Tags: html, css

My page has a div tag with `id=divid` and an anchor tag whose `href` has the value `#divid.`

My href link appears before the div tag and I wrote it as :

```
<a href=#divid>go to div</a>
```

So that when link is clicked it should scroll to show the mentioned div. But the problem is I want that the div should not be visible when page loads instead it must be visible when the link is clicked but it fails to do so.

I wrote it as :`<div id="divid" style="display:none;">bla bla</div>`

when I remove the `display :none` it works fine but otherwise not at all.
Sorry for the unclear tag structure since string followed by starting tags are not shown here so I removed them.

Comment: please provide your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to integrate some JavaScript & CSS for this. The steps will be:

1. Your CSS will have to hide the DIV you want hidden
2. In the anchor's onClick, you clear the class that's hiding the DIV:

   ```
   <body>
       <a href="#myhiddensection" onClick="document.getElementById('myhiddensection').style.display='block';">Go there!</a>
       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
       <div>Nothing below to see at load!</div>
       <div id="myhiddensection" style="display: none">Hello there!</div>
   </body>
   ```

Do note that the above example is using pure JS. If you were to use something like jQuery it could be much cleaner as below and you wouldn't have to worry about weird cross-browser quirks:

```
<body>
    <a href="#myhiddensection" onClick="$('#myhiddensection').show();">Go there!</a>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div>Nothing below to see at load!</div>
    <div id="myhiddensection" style="display: none">Hello there!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with simple CSS:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#a">a</a>

<div id="a" class="page"> this is a id content...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a{
 display:none;
}

#a:target{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: @user2978126 if my answer helped, you can accept the answer by clicking on tick mark lies left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your div id display:none
rather than writing 
you can write this

```
 <a onclick="scrolltodiv();"></a>
 <script>
 function scrolltodiv(){
     var topPosition = $('#divid').scrollTop().top;
     $(window).scrollTop(topPosition);
 }
 </script>
```

and if you not using jQuery just use document.getElementById it would simply work

Comment: Hey thanks.. I was not able to try this way.But surely will try and update you on this. Anyways thanks again for help.